# How 301 redirect with react js reach router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reach-router

We developed web application using react js and we used **reach router** for routing URL. Now we have to redirect our old url to new url with header status 301 status code. But we don't know how to do this with **reach router**. As per document we can redirect one URL to another using below script. but here there is no document about how to set header status code during routing.
URL:- https://reach.tech/router/api/Redirect

```js
<Router>
   <Redirect from="/old-page" to="new-url"/>
   <Routes path="*" />
</Router
```

Please help me to redirect 301 old URL to new URL with permanent redirect with status code 301.

Comment: Stuck with same, guessing, there isn't a solution since the ROOT cause is React is rendering on client side. You can achieve a 301  with the help of a server configured with ngnix or so.